# Run scoverage from intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scoverage

I was wondering, is it possible to run scoverage from intellij (not from the terminal ) and even better, see scoverage reports like the native coverage from intellij?

Thanks

Comment: Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12223.

Comment: Done! didn't know about that

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to collect coverage by adding `scalac-scoverage-plugin` as a test dependency:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.scoverage" %% "scalac-scoverage-plugin" % "1.4.0" % Test
```

[image: coverage results]

Comment: It's not `scoverage` that is used here. Built-in IntelliJ coverage is used (the one which is used for Java). You can verify that by running example from https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin#statement-coverage and see that 100% coverage is shown even though only 33% is covered. Added library dependency doesn't affect anything actually.